# Why print cannot be used with for on the same line in python 2/3?

Tags: python

I would love to implement the following:

```
print(i) for i in xrange(10)
```

However, this does not work in neither python2 nor python3. What is the limitation of the language? Or what did I do wrong?

Comment: if this statement can be written as `for i in xrange(10): print(i)`, why would  there would be a second way of writing it?

Comment: the hack `[print(i) for i in range(10)]` should work in python3 ...

Comment: you can use `for i in xrange(10): print(i)` but probably nobody puts any function in one line with `for` because it makes code less readable.

Comment: It's simply not valid syntax, for either current major Python version, per https://docs.python.org/2/reference/index.html and https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html. You can't just have a generator expression on its own as a valid statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Set builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) (called generator expressions in Python) only work when you are building a set.**  The notation you are using is set builder notation (generator expressions) (something like `x for x in range(10) if ...`).  That being said, you can use a regular for loop

```
for i in xrange(10):
    print(i)
```

or set builder notation building an empty set:

```
>>> x = [print(i) for i in xrange(10)]
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
>>> x
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>>
```

The reason the set has all the none values is because you are never adding to the set, but only printing stuff out.

Comment: That's a *generator expression*, it can be used in e.g. set, dict and list comprehensions but there's no such thing as *"set builder notation"* in Python.

Comment: Please see the link at the top.

Comment: Interesting - never heard it called that before @jonrsharpe.  Learn something everyday :)  Post edited

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
for i in xrange(10): print(i)
```

You could also do something like this, but only in Python 3 where `print` is a function. This is an abuse of generator expressions, though.

```
any(print(i) for i in range(10))
```

Comment: "Why print cannot be used with for on the same line in python 2/3?"  'Why' is the key word. You never actually answer the question.

Comment: But it can, as I have demonstrated. Twice.

Comment: Ok - you do demonstrate that it is possible.  You don't explain why his isn't working.

Comment: You didn't explain why OP's particular attempt failed, which was the implied main question.

Comment: Because for code to be run by the Python interpreter, it must be written in Python. The question is equivalent to "Why isn't Python something other than Python?"

Answer (score 1):

The form `x for x in <sequence>` is meant to result in a list. It was originally this:

```
>>> [i for i in range(10)] 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

introduced in Python 2.0, [Python Enhancement Proposal 202](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/), coming from a variation of uses of map() and filter(). Those functions, and list comprehensions, originate with functional programming environments, which tend to lean towards no-side-effects and no-surprise-state-changes and so on.

In the case where list comprehensions support a function call, it's intended for something like this simple transformation:

```
>>> [math.sin(x) for x in whatever]
[0.1, 0.2, ...]
```

The function is intended to change one list item into a new list item - and the output is still a list.

This syntax lost the surrounding brackets `[ ]` a couple of years later in [PEP289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) as they became more memory-efficient Generator Comprehensions in Python 2.4. These are intended for when you don't need the full list output *as a list* because you are processing all the contents as soon as you get them - e.g. `sum(i for i in range(10))` can add up all the numbers as they appear, without waiting for the full sequence to finish computing first.

The way you want to use it - `print(x) for x in <sequence>` is in the form of a generator comprehension, but you don't want the generator, the list, the sequence. You only want to do it for a side effect which happens when you call the function.

That's not impossible, you can do this in Python 2

```
import sys
[sys.stdout.write(str(i) + '\n') for i in range(10)]
```

and as @wim notes in a comment, this in Python 3:

```
[print(i) for i in range(10)]
```

However, print() doesn't return anything useful, the newly built list or generator is irrelevant and immediately thrown away.

This structure is confusing/misleading to people reading your code, you are explicitly using the "I want to build a list" format when you don't want to build a list.

It's also against the original ideas of list comprehensions and their origins in functional programming - it's much easier to reason about things when they don't have side effects.

From the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

- Explicit is better than implicit.

If you want to iterate over a sequence and print something, explicitly iterate over a list and print it (`for item in sequence: print(item)`). Don't start with "I'm going to build a new list, oh I sneakily printed something as a side effect, then threw the list away".

It's hard to read your intent - did you mean to do that? What did you want it to do?

It's harder to explain - what does this code do? "It builds a new list of `None`s which are the return values from printing the list items". That's putting the focus of what's happening in all the wrong places.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is syntactically incorrect but you can do actually do it in one line using print as a function and do it without the need for the explicit for loop:

```
print(*range(10), sep="\n")
```

Would be equivalent to:

```
 for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

and output:

```
In [32]: print(*range(10),sep="\n")
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
In [2]: print(*range(10))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

And in python2 you just need to import `print_function`:

```
from __future__ import print_function

In [3]: print(*xrange(10),sep="\n")
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
In [4]: print(*xrange(10))
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

or using `str.join`:

```
print("\n".join(map(str,range(10))))
```